# Powershell Error: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. The argument is null or empty

Tags: powershell, parameters, path, uninstallation, start-process

I am trying to test the uninstallation of a program that is installed on my device. I am not sure what I need to do to specify the file path to this exe located on my device. Eventually this will need to be deployed organization wide, that's why I am attempting to use $PSScriptRoot. How do I specify the filepath to the exe I need deleted? It's a simple script but I keep getting the below error:

```
Transcript started, output file is C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Python3.7.8Install.log
2022-10-26-03-08-47 -   Install 
Start-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'FilePath'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\Users\grayvi02\Downloads\UpdatePython.ps1:13 char:27
+ $Process1 = Start-Process $Install_Path -ArgumentList $Install_Args - ...
+                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
 
2022-10-26-03-08-47 -   Error - Install error with exitcode 
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\Python3.7.8Install.log
```

```
$OutputFile = "$env:WINDIR\TEMP\Python3.7.8Install.log"
Writelog $Install_File = "python-3.7.8-amd64.exe"
Writelog $Install_Path = "`"$PSScriptRoot\$Install_File`""
$Install_Args = " /quiet /uninstall"
##########ERROR LOGGING#####
Function Set-WriteToLog ($Write1)
{
    Write-Host "$(Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm-ss)`t-`t$Write1"
}
#########START OF SCRIPT BODY#############
Start-Transcript -Path $OutputFile
set-WriteToLog "Install $Install_File"
$Process1 = Start-Process $Install_Path -ArgumentList $Install_Args -Wait -NoNewWindow -passthru
$ErrorVal = $Process1.exitcode
If (@(0,1641,3010) -contains $Process1.exitcode)
{
    Set-WriteToLog "Success - Install $Install_File with exitcode $ErrorVal"
}
else
{
    Set-WriteToLog "Error - Install error with exitcode $ErrorVal"
}
Stop-Transcript
Exit $LASTEXITCODE
```

Comment: is `WriteLog` a function? You're passing it a variable assignment which is probably just writing to the log (*if not erroring*) and no assigning it to the actual variable.

Comment: When you use `" inside the string for $Install_Path, the double quotation mark will be added to the argument for FilePath. Thus Start-Process can't validate the path. Try removing those.